# That it is better to ajax in rails with json or js.erb? which is faster and why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json

That it is better to ajax in rails with controller return json or return js.erb?
which is faster and why?

Comment: I'm not a professional, but I use json and js.erb for different things. I use json to return values from the server, and the js.erb to execute some javascript that needs server-side information (like change div classes to show error messages with jquery). The js.erb file is a template, which is called after an action.

Comment: I also use exactly the same but now all I want to rewrite into json or js.erb. But I don `t know which one to choose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think speed is the issue here (both options will perform more or less equally).

The keys are *maintainability* and *testability*. What do you prefer?

1. Javascript (worst, rjs, a weird JS/Ruby mixture) scattered all over views on the server side of you app (very, very hard to test).
2. Centralized JS code that gets data from the server and that can be developed and tested as a unit.

I definitely prefer this second option: on the AJAX section of your app make the server return JSON and manage the responses with Javascript in the client. Now that Rails ships with CoffeeScript by default (hint: use also [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)), it's also a joy to write client code.

Comment: js.erb is harder to test too. if you only return json then it's much easier to write a good set of specs for your javascript